# How can I send my data from react-native to my python server

Tags: python, react-native

Currently, I am doing a project to do a tts(Text to Speech) by using AI mimic voice. I was able to make a tts program by using python, but I don't know how to connect it with my application.

This is my github code https://github.com/2021-2-HYU-AI/front-end

This is the java code to send a message.

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Dimensions, TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { GiftedChat } from 'react-native-gifted-chat';
import { AntDesign } from '@expo/vector-icons'; 

const {height, width} = Dimensions.get("window")

function Chat({navigation: {goBack}}) {
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
    const onSend = useCallback((messages = []) => {
        // console.log('previousMessages: ',previousMessages)
        console.log('messages: ', messages)
        setMessages(previousMessages => GiftedChat.append(previousMessages, messages))
    }, [])

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1}}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => goBack()}>
                    <AntDesign name="left" size={24} color="black" />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.headerText}>메세지 남기기</Text>
            </View>
        <GiftedChat
            placeholder={'메세지를 입력하세요...'}
            alwaysShowSend={true}
            messages={messages}
            textInputProps={{ keyboardAppearance: 'dark', autoCorrect: false }}
            onSend={messages => onSend(messages)}
            user={{
                _id: 1,
            }}
        />
        </View>
        
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        flex: 0.1,
        alignItems: "center",
        flexDirection: "row",
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        borderBottomColor: "black",
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
    },
    headerText: {
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: "500",
        marginLeft: 5,
    }
});
```

and this is the python code that I am making.

```
import requests
import os

path=os.getcwd()
print(path)


def download(url, file_name):
    with open(file_name,"wb") as file:
        response=requests.get(url)
        file.write(response.content)

if __name__=='__main__':
    text=input('메시지 입력 : ')
    url="http://localhost:5000/tts-server/api/infer-glowtts?text="+text
    download(url, "TTS.mp3")
```

and this is the python code that I want to connect it.

[chat.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMh5j.png)
If I type the message I want the text message to go to the python to `text=input` part and do the tts automatically. Thank you for reading my post.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an open API for this to work